# Share code between client and server side

Tags: android, eclipse, playframework

I'm developing an Android app with Play framework as backend. There are some classes that are common between the client and server side projects.

If I create a library project or a shared folder in Eclipse, and link the classes to both projects, Play complains that it cannot find the classes, (maybe because it has to be in a folder called 'app'?)

Is it possible to share code between client and server side projects using Play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was link the 'app' folder and specify an inclusion pattern for the shared package.

the problem with jar is that the server needs to be restarted everytime it changes, the source needs to be repackaged and the project needs to be re-eclipsified. As for the library project, i'm not using any android specific code in the shared folders

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Play framework, but if you create a library in Eclipse, instead of linking to it in the build path you must add it as a library in the android settings of your project. (You find them by selecting your project and pressing alt+enter)

Answer (score 1):

Play uses his own classloader and classpath. So you must put your classes into a jar and this into the lib. Or you create a module for the shared code.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be:

1. Create a new project with the code to share. This should provide an API to do what you want to do.
2. Build the project as a JAR
3. Link the Jar on PLay (drop it on lib folder) and Android